# How to get random questions from three or four table without repeating questions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am doing online aptitude test, which will pick up 10 random questions from database and display them on webpage for answering.

Now I am displaying questions from one table.

Problem is that I have to pick 10 questions from each 3 to 4 tables and display it randomly without repeating the questions. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(1);
include("database.php");
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
extract($_SESSION);
/*$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=9",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs))
{
unset($_SESSION[qn]);
exit;
}*/
if(isset($subid) && isset($testid))
{
$_SESSION[sid]=$subid;
$_SESSION[tid]=$testid;
header("location:quiz.php");
}
if(!isset($_SESSION[sid]) || !isset($_SESSION[tid]))
{
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Quiz</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
include("header.php");
$myDate = date('y/m/d');

$query="SELECT * FROM mst_question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";

$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=9 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
if(!isset($_SESSION[qn]))
{
    $_SESSION[qn]=0;
    mysql_query("delete from mst_useranswer where sess_id='" . session_id() ."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $_SESSION[trueans]=0;

}
else
{   
        if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
        {
                mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);

                $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
                mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', 9,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
                if($ans==$row[7])
                {
                            $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
                }
                $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
        }
        else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans))
        {
                mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
                $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
                mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', 9,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
                if($ans==$row[7])
                {
                            $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
                }
                echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
                $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
                echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
                echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
                $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
                echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
                echo "</table>";
                mysql_query("insert into mst_result(login,test_id,test_date,score) values('$login',9,'$myDate',$_SESSION[trueans])") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<h1 align=center><a href=review.php> Review Question</a> </h1>";
                unset($_SESSION[qn]);
                unset($_SESSION[sid]);
                unset($_SESSION[tid]);
                unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
                exit;
        }
}
$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=9 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
{
unset($_SESSION[qn]);
echo "<h1 class=head1>Some Error  Occured</h1>";
session_destroy();
echo "Please <a href=index.php> Start Again</a>";

exit;
}
mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
$row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Next Question'></form>";
else
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'></form>";
echo "</table></table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't had enough caffeine yet this morning to read through your code, but in an app I'm writing I need 30K random images without repeats. I first let the database pick the ids ("Select id from mytable order by rand() limit 30000"), then I work through the list that was returned and get the data as needed.

Comment: I don't think you should be getting any repeats with your current query.  Unless you have duplicates in the database.  Are you?

Comment: Randomizing is something you should do in your code, not in your database. I'd suggest first pulling all of the questions from the database and inserting them into an array. Next in a `for` loop that iterates 10 times generating random numbers (within the appropriate range) and use them as indexes to take random questions out of your array and put into an array of the 10 questions you require.

Comment: Is it possible to UNION table results such that you might be able to `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT 10` the overall result set?

Comment: no duplicate values in table, yet questions are repeating,..more over i need to pick 10 ten questions from each table randomly and display it,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using distinct:

```
$rs=mysql_query("select distinct * from mst_question where test_id=9 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10",$cn)
```